# .take() operator is not working on the Observables

Tags: angular6, rxjs6

The service returns me an array with 40 objects but all I need in my app are the first 5. I've made some research and I found out that the operator that fit the case is Take, but it doesn't do anything: when I call the service, it returns me all the 40 elements.

What am I doing wrong?

In the service:

```
getData(valueS): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.from(
        this.http.get<any>(`${this.URL}`)
    );
}
```

In my component's ts:

```
this.dataService.getData(this.valueSelected)
        .pipe(
            delay(1000),
            take(5)
        )
        .subscribe((res: any) => {
            this.dataContainer = res.main;
            console.log(res);
            console.log(this.dataContainer);
            this.buildWidget();
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/take.html), the `.take()` operator does this:

> emit only the first n items emitted by an Observable

Unless your service is emitting the 40 objects one by one, then `take` is not a good operator to do what you want. What you need is probably just the native `.slice()` from javascript, which you can use Observable's `.map()` operator to manipulate it:

```
this.dataService.getData(this.valueSelected)
    .pipe(
        delay(1000),
        map(arr=>arr.slice(0,5))//take the first five elements
    )
    .subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.dataContainer = res.main;
        console.log(res);
        console.log(this.dataContainer);
        this.buildWidget();
    });
```

Comment: Oh, indeed now. I didn't understand that the values should be emitted one by one. Sad. Well, thank you!